# Oracle query - adding a total per category to a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following columns:

```
record_id
category_id
item_id
quantity
```

There are multiple records for each item_id.

I wrote a query that pulls all the items along with the category and total quantity for each item:

```
SELECT b.category_name, a.item_id, SUM(a.quantity)
FROM Table1 a, Table2 b
WHERE a.category_id = b.category_id
GROUP BY b.category_name, a.item_name
```

Now I want to display one more column - total quantity of all items in a specific category.
How can I do that without using functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions . . . and `JOIN`:

```
SELECT b.category_name, a.item_id, SUM(a.quantity),
       SUM(SUM(a.quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY b.category_name) a category_quantity
FROM Table1 a JOIN
     Table2 b
     ON a.category_id = b.category_id
GROUP BY b.category_name, a.item_name;
```